# type casting lambda with capture to c style typedef function type

Tags: c++

I have been writing a C library wrapper for (openwrt)ubus for some time now and it works fine; but it uses a macro to generate lambda, which I am not proud or happy with. And now I'd like to add some more functionality, but current approach is limiting this.

Current wrapper library can be found from [here](https://github.com/oskarirauta/ubus_cpp/tree/main)
Unfortunately it is not compilable unless you have certain libraries that are available generally on openwrt; but from source code, you can see my macro; which I'd like to be able to loose.

Anyway.. Here's struct that I need to construct:

```
struct ubus_method {
          const char *name;
          ubus_handler_t handler;
  
          unsigned long mask;
          unsigned long tags;
          const struct blobmsg_policy *policy;
          int n_policy;
 };
```

never mind about other things, it's the ubus_handler_t which I am struggling with;
ubus_handler_t is

```
typedef int (*ubus_handler_t)(struct ubus_context *ctx, struct ubus_object *obj,
                                 struct ubus_request_data *req,
                                 const char *method, struct blob_attr *msg);
```

This has been discussed here very often and solution provided, is to use std::function - but as this is already defined in externed "C" library, I cannot change this - unless I make my own fork which is not a option.

So, what I need to do - is to add a capture to my lambda, but ubus_handler_t fails with it. I also need it to *escape* if it's inside a class, as otherwise it's once again not compatible with ubus_handler_t - all my ideas so far, have fallen; once I figure out one way, there's another problem with that work-around, like using a method inside class which is not static - I even made my *own* ubus_method2, which has handler defined as a function, I added one more variable to end of ubus_method with std::function type, and then handler called it... Well, by far that was great idea; unfortunately it was not possible to cast it as ubus_method even though structs were very near to be identical.. So I added a function inside that would *convert* to ubus_method - well, nice - but handler couldn't be used again as it's not a static member.. #undef and redefinition of ubus_method - failure..

Anyway- days have passed and still, only solution that works, so far is that macro - but something else must be a better solution to the issue.

Some sample code without ubus stuff that has similar technique used:

```
struct method {
          const char *name;
          handler_t handler;
};

typedef int (*handler_t)(const char*);
```

How can I store a handler in method with either as a lambda with capture - or as a std::function, in a way, that it still would be accepted as handler_t..

Source for ubus, is [here](https://git.openwrt.org/?p=project/ubus.git;a=tree)

I found a solution to my problem; It just didn't work after some tests. Decided to share this anyway..

I copied ubus_method, ubus_object_type and ubus_object to ubus_method2, ubus_object_type2 and ubus_object2- to the end of ubus_method I added a std::function f - then I made ubus_object_type2 and ubus_object2 to use ubus_method2 instead of ubus_method.

Before adding object, I changed my ubus_method2 to void* which I then casted as ubus_method - this worked perfectly, I just had to find it through object -> methods (with name comparison) and cast my method inside a *general callback* to ubus_method2 - and execute f..

Until.. I added multiple methods to object. Segmentation faults. Without going to any deeper, I think it's because of that ubus_method2's size is bigger than ubus_method's because it has more content. Internally it handles ubus_object, not ubus_object2 and inside - it fails.

Eventually I decided to have a static std::map<std::string<std::map<std::string, std::function<...>>> which I use to store functions. I don't like it. But it's so far best solution.

Comment: *Capturing* lambdas are not compatible with C-style function pointers.  Period.  Only *non-capturing* lambdas are compatible. If `ubus_handler_t` allows you to pass around user-defined data, then you can use that to pass around an object holding your desired data/methods, otherwise using a thunk or global/thread-local variables is the only option.

Comment: Lambda or whatever other solutions available suites for me just fine- as long as it solves the problem... and doesn't require boost libraries. It seems I'm stuck with that macro which so far has worked out; but to improve my library, I would need find another way for this.

Comment: C-callback should have a `void* userData` as parameter to allow extra parameter...

Comment: That would be perfect in my opinion too.. But there isn't one. It's not bad coding, it's just not designed for C++ - nor wrappers like this.

Comment: I added link to ubus sources. I was wondering; if I would make copies of few structs, just enough for this, such as ubus_method, ubus_object_type and ubus_object - and then make my own versions of ubus_add_object and ubus_add_object_cb - which would then work with my slightly modified struct versions.... This way I wouldn't need to fork it completely, just partially.. Sounds very complicated though. And after working with this so long.. Not sure if it would work any better..

Comment: You might be able to derive from `ubus_method` to store additional data there.

Comment: In any case, supplying additional context data is a normal use case and that lib should really support it in some way. So, either it does already and you haven't found it or it has a serious deficiency. Either way, I'd contact the authors by filing a bug ticket or support request.

Comment: Objects have a way to deliver user data, but it's not for method definitions; objects usually have void* priv that carries extra data, but it is not available for methods - or even type objects as it's already used internally.